# Why would we ever want to use git add -u?

Tags: git

If I understand difference options for git add correctly, git add -u only adds modified and deleted files to the staging area, whereas git add . adds not only modified and deleted files but also untracked files. So I was wondering why we would ever wanna use git add -u when there's git add . or git add -A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use it a lot:

- If `git status` tells me that there are various modified files that are not staged for commit, and I want to add exactly those files, `git add -u` adds exactly those files without me having to think about it.
- If `git status` tells me that there are various modified files, and/or other files, where I don't want to en-masse add *everything* that `git status` mentioned, I run `git diff` and `git diff --staged`<sup>1</sup> if/as desired, `git add` individually, maybe an occasional `git add -p`, etc.
- If `git status` tells me that there are untracked files that I *do* want to add, I may use `git add .` (I use this rarely / sparingly so as to accidentally avoid adding files that should remain untracked; if `git status` shows untracked files that I *don't* want, I add them to an appropriate `.gitignore` first, but I still tend not to run `git add .`.)

Note that while `git add -A` will "add" a removal (and `git add file-i-removed` will do the same thing), my brain balks at this construct: I use `git rm` for it instead.

---

<sup>1</sup>My fingers are wired to type this as `git diff --cached`, actually.  These do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Totally agree (FWIW, I have the extra habit to always run `git add -v .` instead of `git add .`, so running `git status` yet another time is unneeded :)

Answer (score 1):

Short form: it depends on your build/test cycle. If you generate a lot of detritus or other local-only work and it's easier to just step around it than manage it explicitly, `git add -u` makes it drop-dead easy to add only the stuff git already knows you care about.

Maybe you're generating something like UI-trace datasets to feed unit tests and have a lot of candidates, you explicitly add the ones worth tracking and use `git add -u` to apply any autogenerated updates (like say to keep the datasets current with changes to your trace driver).

Sure, you could make a "don't track these" directory and keep the not-ready-for-prime-time stuff in there, but that's more tedious than just using `git add -u`.